# Splitting DXF layers into Shapefile layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dxf, splitting

When I load a DXF into QGIS all the layers are present in the attribute table. Is it possible to split this "entities" layer in QGIS into its component parts and save each component part as an individual shapefile.

I am at present selecting each layer and right clicking and saving as .shp. But is there a fast way because this way is time consuming and boring?

Comment: see also [Convert multi-layer DWG into several KML or geoJSON files (one per layer)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162135/convert-multi-layer-dwg-into-several-kml-or-geojson-files-one-per-layer "Convert multi-layer DWG into several KML or geoJSON files (one per layer)") for an OGR/command line method of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wil need to define a field to split them with, if you don't already have one.
Then use the split layer.
[image: split layer]

Comment: Excellent. Stupid me did not think of the dxf as a vector layer despite the fact i added it as one. Spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I do that before I load the dxf into QGIS. I use DoubleCAD XT (which is free) to export one layer at a time from the cad package.

DoubleCAD is also useful for going the other way, dxfs out of QGIS aren't very appealing to other users, but if you open them in DoubleCAD and save them as DWG I find I get better results. Often I will rebuild the layers in this way as well.

Comment: Good answer. However, it may be me looking for a quick way to do it, but is there a way (similar to how i can classify the layers and assign different colour) when two clicks and it dismantle the entire layer?