# Convert multi-layer DWG into several KML or geoJSON files (one per layer)

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, dxf, dwg

I have some big DWG files, with 5 to 50 layers, which I draw and geolocated using AutoCAD (with some external modules).
 I need to convert them to KML or geoJSON so that the JS library can load them and display them on the map.

I used AutoCAD to export my .DWG into .DXF, then I installed GDAL and used ogr2ogr to convert those DXFs into geoJSON. It works, but the generated geoJSON is very big (more than 10 megabytes) and it loads forever once I try to display it into a google map or a leaflet map.

What I would like to do, is to have a separated geoJSON/KML for every layer of my DWG/DXF file, so that I can load and display each layer separately which hopefully would increase performance.

I am trying to have an automated workflow, because as I have a lot of files, it would take too much time to take every one of them and split layers manually.

Any idea ?

Comment: the link to the code is no longer working. Would you please update it. 
BTW in case others hit the same issue, I first had to convert my AutoCAD DWG to DXF using the free tool you can find [here](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/TeighaFileConverter).

Comment: the gist seems to be gone. But the OGR thing still works. You could pack multiple DXF layers in one output file by changing the SQL to something like `select * from entities where LAYER in (…)` and not have to muck around with js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up making a node.js script which uses ogr2ogr through the command line.

It calls ogr2ogr through a spawned child process to keep it async.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs epsg:2154 -t_srs epsg:4326 dest_file.json source_file.dxf
```

Then it reads the new geoJSON file into node, groups features in featureCollection by Layer name, wraps each group into a geoJSON container, and writes each wrapped group to a separate ".json" file.

[Code is available here](https://gist.github.com/Rayjax/58ea387b49f1c165474f)

Comment: That's a dead link now. Any chance of sharing it again?

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 3):

It should be quite easy by using DXF, ogr2ogr, and GDAL SQLite SQL dialect http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html.

Demo:

Download some sample data, for example http://justcad.com/jcsample.dxf

Use ogrinfo with SQLite dialect for getting a list of layers:

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select distinct LAYER  from entities" jcsample.dxf
INFO: Open of `jcsample.dxf'
      using driver `DXF' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 5
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Layer: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  Layer (String) = PAPER

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  Layer (String) = FRELEV

OGRFeature(SELECT):2
  Layer (String) = LSELEV

OGRFeature(SELECT):3
  Layer (String) = RRELEV

OGRFeature(SELECT):4
  Layer (String) = RSELEV
```

Convert the layer "PAPER" into GeoJSON. I will assign epsg:3857 as a dummy projection because otherwise GDAL would assume EPSG:4326 which would make no sense because coordinate values in this data are out of the valid range.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -a_srs epsg:3857 -dialect SQLite -sql "select * from entities where LAYER='PAPER'" paper.json jcsample.dxf
```

Check the result:

```
ogrinfo -ro -al paper.json
INFO: Open of `paper.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: OGRGeoJSON
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 56
Extent: (-174.786500, -1163.622000) - (1769.214000, 204.378100)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.
x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Layer: String (0.0)
SubClasses: String (0.0)
ExtendedEntity: String (0.0)
Linetype: String (0.0)
EntityHandle: String (0.0)
Text: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(OGRGeoJSON):0
  Layer (String) = PAPER
  SubClasses (String) = (null)
  ExtendedEntity (String) = (null)
  Linetype (String) = CONTINUOUS
  EntityHandle (String) = (null)
  Text (String) = (null)
  LINESTRING (1644.348 -1051.956 0,1763.214 -1051.956 0)

OGRFeature(OGRGeoJSON):1
  Layer (String) = PAPER
  SubClasses (String) = (null)
  ExtendedEntity (String) = (null)
  Linetype (String) = CONTINUOUS
  EntityHandle (String) = (null)
  Text (String) = (null)
  LINESTRING (1644.348 -1066.961 0,1763.214 -1066.961 0)

OGRFeature(OGRGeoJSON):2
  Layer (String) = PAPER
  SubClasses (String) = (null)
  ExtendedEntity (String) = (null)
  Linetype (String) = CONTINUOUS
  EntityHandle (String) = (null)
  Text (String) = (null)
  LINESTRING (1644.348 -1081.244 0,1763.214 -1081.244 0)
...
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my DXFs are in Lambert93 (EPSG:2154). Can I do the projection to target coordinate system (WGS 84) directly ? Anyway, thanks a lot, I didn't know at all about the SQLite feature of GDAL. Will give it a shot

Comment: Sure, `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs epsg:2154 -t_srs epsg:4326 ... `. It is documented in http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. SQLite dialect is very powerful because you can use all these functions with it https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: It does work :) . I was wondering if I could make a command that would make a file for every layer, without having to specify layer names manually. It would make a select distinct on layers as a subquery, and use the result layers names in a loop and extract each one of them using the second query you gave me. Any idea of how to do this without using third party tools ?

Comment: That sounds like scripting. Let's hope somebody comes to rescue with a Python script.

Comment: I made a JS script (with node.js) to achieve this, and it works. At first, I used the mysql way, querying layer names and then looping over them, but I has problems with exotic layer names not passing in the queries. I ended up using simple conversion to geoJSON, then splitting the geoJSON itself into several geoJSONs.Will had an answer with it. Thanks for your help

Comment: (upvoted yours and accepted mine)